# Wanting to create a simple app that outputs data from form

Tags: angularjs

This is going to be a very simple app, just need to put a form, that will display the values, like the 2 way binding tutorials, but I need to be able to add multiple values, so once I have added one value, I hit a button or something, and it saves that value, and I can add more. I have googled, and googled, but maybe don't know the right question to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a simple example, hope that's what you need

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.users = []
  defaultUser = {
    name: '',
    sex: 'female',
    age: '',
    planet: 'Uranus',
    hobby: ''
  }

  $scope.user = defaultUser

  $scope.addUser = function () {
    $scope.users.push(angular.copy($scope.user))
    $scope.user = defaultUser
  }
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZTzdpU69R4IUaRojv2Yl?p=preview

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly the idea. I am trying to output it into plain text, basically what I am doing is making a fast way to generate 301's from a clients old site, so in PHP I would echo out the html (ie. Redirect 301 {{old value}} /{{new-value}} or something along those lines, then be able to copy the whole thing and paste into .htaccess. Like I said, very basic.